# Send email on new comment when no admin approval needed?

Tags: plugin-recommendation, comments, notifications

I see that if I turn off "An administrator must always approve the comment" and "Comment author must have a previously approved comment" I get no notifications of new comments on my site.

Can I somehow make it send the notification even though approvals are unchecked in dashboard under "discussion settings"?

And what would be a good way to send this notification to all users registered on this website, and not only to admin? I tried [WP Comment Notifier For All (Wordpress Plugin)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-comment-notifier-for-all/).

but it didn't work...

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mmm, well [Comments Notifier (Wordpress Plugin)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/comments-notifier/) did the trick

Comment: Please select the answer - even if it is yours - as answer so the question get's marked as answered. Thanks.

Comment: of course, but you can do so after 48 hours have passed =)